# how to make it so only a specific amount of values in a list, python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

i want my program so that you are only able to have a maximum of 3 values in the list, is there anyway to do this?

```
    if group == "A":
         if name in groupA:
             groupA = pickle.load(open("groupA.p", "rb"))
             groupA[name] = [count] 
             groupA[name].append(count)
             pickle.dump(groupA, open("groupA.p", "wb"))
         else:
            score = [count]
            groupA[name] = [count]
            pickle.dump(groupA, open("groupA.p", "wb"))
```

thank you!

Answer (score 1):

After appending, you can check the length of the list and remove items from the front for as long as necessary to reach the maximum length again:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

while len(lst) > 3:
    lst.pop(0) # remove the first item

print(lst) # [6, 7, 8]
```

Of course, if you only ever append a single item, you don’t need a while loop but can just use a single if instead.